# TBB task execute sometimes not called

Tags: c++, multithreading, tbb

**EDIT**: I'm using Windows 10 64bit with TBB 2018 Update 2

I have 2 `tbb::task`s:

```
struct QueueProcessingTask : public tbb::task
{
    QueueProcessingTask();
    ~QueueProcessingTask();

    task *execute();
};

struct MainScanTask : public tbb::task
{
    MainScanTask();
    ~MainScanTask();

    task *execute();

    QueueProcessingTask *m_pTask;
};
```

In my main manager object I have an instance of

```
MainScanTask *m_mainTask;
```

And I'm calling

```
m_mainTask = new(tbb::task::allocate_root()) MainScanTask();
m_mainTask->execute();
```

where `execute` is

```
tbb::task *MainScanTask::execute()
{
    m_pTask = new(allocate_continuation())QueueProcessingTask();
    if (!m_pTask)
    {
        Trace("allocate_continuation() failed");
        return NULL;
    }
    QueueProcessingTask& task1 = *m_pTask;
    Trace("Spawning");
    spawn(task1);
    Trace("Spawned");

    return m_pTask;
}
```

This part works well. However, once in a while (could be every 10 runs, or could be every 1000 runs), the call to `spawn(task1)` doesn't seems to call `QueueProcessingTask`'s `execute()` and therefor causes an access violation on later parts of the run.

I have log prints in which are sometimes not being printed

```
tbb::task *QueueProcessingTask::execute()
{
    Trace("QueueProcessingTask::execute() 1"); 
    RunPipeLine(); // Launches tbb::pipeline
    Trace("QueueProcessingTask::execute() 2");
    return NULL;
}
```

My questions are:

- Why? is there a better way of implementing such mechanism
- Can I detect such situation and maybe try and spawn again?

Comment: Your code is incorrect; you both spawn `m_pTask` and return it from `execute()` for immediate processing. It may result in the task being executed twice as well as other incorrect behavior. What do you try to achieve?

Comment: The return of 'm_pTask' is an addition after the problem appeared. Its point is to try and see in an upper level if the allocation failed and stop processing to prevent the access violation. We know now that the problem is not in the allocation so it's probably not needed anymore . Why is it a problem to return a pointer to the task?

Comment: I missed that you call `m_mainTask->execute()` directly. OK, in that case returning a task pointer is less of a problem (though still bad, because you have spawned this task - so another thread can execute and *destroy* it at any time).

I suggest you prepare a MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and describe the desired behavior and how what you observe differs from it.